# Synchronized code updating

Tags: php, version-control, collaboration, liveedit

I work in a small team working on a PHP project, one of the problems is we are all working on the same project at the same time. Sometimes we get to the point where we end up editing the same file and one version of that file overwrites the other.
Like Google Docs i noticed only the other day when a another user is typing away on the screen the others viewing that file can also see live what they are doing. I was wondering is there a way to do that with coding? see what my team is doing, live.

Any suggestions? Do you know some ways I can increase my teams productivity?

Comment: use source control. git, cvs, svn, etc... every person works on their copy and has to resolve conflicts upon checkin.

Comment: This is where a good version control system with merging (like git) is an important development tool

Answer (score 2):

The closest solution I've seen is something like linux screen + vim|emacs|nano|your favorite editor. Here's an old, but good article explaining how to use it: http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442418-using-screen-for-remote-interaction

Otherwise, you might check out http://collabedit.com/

I like the idea, I don't know that anyone has developed it enough for production use.

Answer (score 2):

The team I work on uses SVN.  Developers each cut a branch from trunk, work on the branch, then merge back into trunk.

We check in our branches nightly, so we don't lose work, and we merge into trunk when our code is "stable".

Doing this, we don't step on each other's toes, and we know that trunk, for the most part, works.